# webrtc to rtp to hls with kurento and AWS Elemental MediaLive

Tags: amazon-web-services, webrtc, kurento

I would like to create webrtc to hlt.
Using Wawza is a good solution, but I cannot manage it.
I want to use aws eternal medialive.
I caught up with a solution with kurento mediaserver that converts webrtc to rtp and, aws converts rtp to  htl.

Is it possible to create a below architecture.

browser => kurento (WebrtcEndpoint) => kurento(rtpEndpoint) => aws eternal medialive.

Comment: Hi, I know it's been some time since you asked this question, but did you manage to make it work?

Answer (score 2):

By the look of things, it's not possible. Kurento's RTP endpoint is SDP based, while MediaLive only supports raw RTP streams without session negotiation.